# Check whether URL includes a certain string in node js

Tags: node.js, express, parsing, url, body-parser

I need to check whether the URL that the user has given as an input has certain strings in node js and create server side validation and display whether this is the correct format of the url that i need.

I used handlebars template engine to get the URL from the user. Here, is the code [Handlebars Template Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DePZh.png).

Now, I have used body-parser to get the value of the input in node.js in json format. Here is the code for it. [POST request code in node js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIUoc.png).

The format of URL that I am giving as an input is https://trade.opskins.com/t/xxxxxxx/xxxxxxxx

I want to check whether https://trade.opskins.com/t/ <- this string is present in the url and create some validation for it.

Does anyone have any idea of how to check whether the url includes the following string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) to check for the URL.

```
url.startsWith('https://trade.opskins.com/t/');
```